# jQuery HTML click event firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a custom select menu button, and I have bound to the html click event to **close** it. But the event is firing twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/GnzBj/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('html').click(function () {
        console.log('html');
    });
});
```

Any one know why/how to prevent it firing twice?

Comment: I have a feeling its because you are binding it to the `html` element...

Comment: What about binding it to the `click` event of the `select` element instead?   http://jsfiddle.net/XzKqC/

Comment: @Calvin.Allen because this is for clicking off the element to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the event is triggered twice is because you have the whole UI inside a `label`.

```
<div  ...>
    <label for="xmod-form-51183d51afa3d" ... >
        <select name="theme" id="xmod-form-51183d51afa3d" ...>
            ...
        </select>
        ...
    </label>
</div>
```

Clicking on the label will also trigger a click event on the form element it relates to.

If you remove the `label` element, it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/GnzBj/5/.

In case you need the `label`, let it contain as few as possible of the UI, but clicking on it will still trigger two events.

Comment: What's the technical reason for the dual firing though?

Comment: @yahelc: That's how labels work. It's great for checkboxes or radio buttons. Clicking on the label will also select the checkbox/radio button. Will see if I can find a proper reference.

Comment: That sounds familiar, but for it to trigger a second click event seems weird. I guess clicking label triggers a click on the child inputs, and as a result of the bubbling triggers a second `<html>` click?

Comment: I tested it with the form control being a sibling of the label and the same happend, two clicks were triggered. The MDN documentation mentions something about synthetic click events, but I don't know if it means this behavior (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label#Click_events_in_nested_<label>_elements). I agree it's a bit strange and I cannot fully explain why this is happening. All I could find in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) was that the associated from control gets focus when the label is focused. I will keep looking.